# Spotfire information link reorganizing fields

Tags: spotfire

When I make an information link in Spotfire my fields get reorganized in alphabetical order. I would like the fields to stay in the order of the original table.

Can someone please help me with a solution to keep my fields in the original order?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but what is the reason for keeping the order of the fields?

Comment: I like to keep certain fields grouped together for a better user experience.

Answer (score 1):

In Information Designer you can use the Move Up / Move Down controls to control the order of columns in the Information Link.

[image: Information Link Move Up and Move Down controls]